# How to render the ReactDOM every second?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React, I'm trying to follow this ticking clock example but do something a bit different. I'd like the `ReactDOM` to be rendered in the `index.js`. Here is my code:

**Timer.js:**

```js
import React from 'react';

const Timer = () => {
    const tick = () => {
        return new Date().toLocaleTimeString().toString();
    };

    const element = (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>
            <h2>It is {tick()} !</h2>
        </div>
    );

    return (
        element
    );
};

export default Timer;
```

**App.js:**

```js
/*jshint esversion: 8 */
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Timer from './Timer'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Timer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**index.js:**

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import App from './App';

setInterval(ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root")), 1000);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

But it only prints the current time on screen, not ticking. Why does the code `setInterval(ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root")), 1000);` not work on `index.js`?

Comment: Because You are immediately calling it in `setInterval()` instead of passing it a callback. Try `setInterval(() => ReactDOM.render(...), 1000)`

Comment: Don't call the `ReactDOM.render` repeatedly. Instead put the logic in the `Timer` component that's going to update your current time every `x` amount of seconds, or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a good practice to avoid calling directly the render function, you could make your `Timer` a Component and let it update with state changes, which is how react would do it with its life cycle. For example:

```
class Timer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      time: new Date().toLocaleTimeString().toString()
    };
  }
  tick() {
    this.setState({
      time: new Date().toLocaleTimeString().toString()
    });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      1000
    );
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalID);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>
            <h2>It is {this.state.time} !</h2>
        </div>
    );
  }
} 

export default Timer;
```

Notice I used two of React cycle functions `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount`, in order to make the component update once again after finished mouting, and the other to clear the interval variable once react unmounts your component.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what is the purpose of defining `props` here? Cannot see it being used anywhere.

Comment: We do this at the beginning of Component constructors, it is a common practice to call the super with the props for proper initialization. You can call it without the argument, it is actually not absolutely required if you don't use the props in your initialization.
You can check here for further info: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

Answer (score 2):

You can use `React.useEffect` passing an array as second argument, which is the equivalent of `componentDidMount`.

You then want to use `setInterval` to set the state every second.

Return a function from `useEffect` to clear the interval when the component unmounts.

See working codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-cherry-mr18m).

You code would look as follows:

```
const function Timer() {
  const [time, setTime] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const tick = () => {
      return new Date().toLocaleTimeString().toString();
    };
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setTime(tick());
      return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return <h2>It is {time} !</h2>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the date field to the state object and in tick function use setInterval to set a new value to state using setState. Use state.date value to show the time. React renders new dom each time state is changed using setState function.

A working example of a timer has been given in react docs, giving it a read will help you lots.
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html